# Can the Feeds module work with get parameters?

Tags: feeds

Is there a way that I can use the Feeds module in Drupal 7 to connect to an API which requires specific get parameters to interact with?

The reply that the API gives will be in a simple XML format. The valuable information will be included in Content. This data will be in JSON format. I want to use this data to be put in a form which users can edit and submit back to the (API) server.

Is this possible? If not, what other solution can you recommend me?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Feeds importer is set to file upload, but you can set it up to fetch data using an HTTP request.

1. On the settings page for your importer, click the **Change** link next to **Fetcher** in the left menu.
2. Select the radio button for **HTTP Fetcher** and hit the **Save button**
3. Visit /import and click on the link for your importer.

There will be a field there where you can enter the URL you want it to retrieve data from.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However it's not really the answer I'm looking for. What I'm trying to achieve with the Feeds module is accessing the API server with queries/parameters. For example: I want to  access the API server with api.php?s=1&q=getApp
How do I set this up in the Feeds module?